# Access Pages, PageHeaders and encodings of a parquet file

Tags: parquet, pyarrow, parquet-mr

I'm having trouble accessing metadata at the Page level of a parquet file.

I'm able to access metadata and encodings at the ColumnChunk level only.

I'm trying to achieve that because encodings at ColumnChunk level often has this value in my files : [RLE, RLE_DICTIONARY, PLAIN] which seems odd to me.
I did read that the Dictionary Page is encoded as plain, which makes sense. And that the dictionary can get full, which means some data pages are using the dictionary and some don't.
The first would be encoded as RLE_DICTIONARY and the second as RLE ?

With pyarrow, I'm able to print metadata at columnChunk level, including the encodings.
But it does not seem to be possible to access Page and PageHeaders.

With the parquet-mr java library, I was able to do the same thing. But I cannot find objects and functions to reach PageHeaders and encoding at Page level.
Does anyone know how to do it ?

Comment: Pyarrow does not have any utilities that I'm aware of to access page-level metadata.  I think the most common explanation for what you are seeing is that the dictionary page (e.g. the entries in the dictionary) are encoded with `PLAIN`. The dictionary indices are encoded with `RLE`.  The whole column then has `RLE_DICTIONARY`.  Is this surprising?

Comment: FWIW, I built parquet-c++ with some debug prints.  The column metadata contains `RLE`, `RLE_DICTIONARY`, and `PLAIN`.  The dictionary pages are encoded with `PLAIN`.  The data pages are encoded with `RLE_DICTIONARY`.  Even though the column metadata contains `RLE` I do not see any pages that have `RLE` encoding.

Comment: Thank you for yours comments. I wasn't aware of the dictionary indices. I saw that repetition and definition levels can be encoded as RLE too.  
I guess there are many reasons to see RLE appearing in column metadata and not in data pages encodings.